# Google Maps API returns empty latitudes and longitudes

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I built a simple map application as referred to the code below.

Long story short, I am receiving the right API calls (name, description etc), but my geometry.location.lat and geometry.location.long seems to be empty (console.log it to see).

(in fact, the markers appear with the correct location coordinates so I'm confused)

[image: screenshot with console output]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Map</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <!-- Stylesheets. -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <h1 class="display-4">My Map</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mb-2">
      <div class="col">
        <input class="form-control" id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div id="map"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Bootstrap scripts. -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Google Maps scripts. -->
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<your api key>&libraries=places" async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
var map;

window.onload = () => {
    let method = 'dynamic';

    // if you want to statically add places, de-comment following line
    // method = 'static';

    if (method === 'static') {
        let places = staticLoadPlaces();
        renderPlaces(places);
    }

    if (method !== 'static') {

        // first get current user location
        return navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {

            console.log("Latitude: ", position.coords.latitude)
            console.log("Longitude: ", position.coords.longitude)

            // works
            var options = {
            center: { lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude },
            zoom: 100
            };

            var myLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);

            var request = {
                location: myLocation,
                radius: '500',
                type: ['restaurant']
              };

            service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
            service.nearbySearch(request, callback);


            ///////////////////////////////////////////
            // Search Function that is optional here //
            ///////////////////////////////////////////
            var input = document.getElementById('search');
            var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);

            map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
            searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
            });

            var markers = [];

            searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function () {
            var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

            if (places.length == 0)
                return;

            markers.forEach(function (m) { m.setMap(null); });
            markers = [];

            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            places.forEach(function(p) {
                if (!p.geometry)
                return;

                markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                title: p.name,
                position: p.geometry.location
                }));

                if (p.geometry.viewport)
                bounds.union(p.geometry.viewport);
                else
                bounds.extend(p.geometry.location);
            });

            map.fitBounds(bounds);
            });

        },

        );
    }
};

function callback(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        var place = results[i];
        console.log(results[i]); // outputs for google maps js api
        console.log(results[i].name);
        console.log(results[i].geometry.location.lat);
        console.log(results[i].geometry.location.lng);
        createMarker(results[i]);
      }
    }
  }

function createMarker(result) {
    new google.maps.Marker({
        position: result.geometry.location,
        map: map
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`LatLng.lat`](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLng.lat) and [`LatLng.lng`](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLng.lng) are functions.

```
    console.log(results[i].geometry.location.lat);
    console.log(results[i].geometry.location.lng);
```

To get the value, call them:

```
    console.log(results[i].geometry.location.lat());
    console.log(results[i].geometry.location.lng());
```